# What iOS Framework is missing?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I keep getting an error that seems like a framework is missing in my app:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_" referenced from:
```

How is it you can tell which framework it is that is missing?  I've been over this and over this, and as it works in other projects, I've compared frameworks, but they're all the same and after hours of work this is driving me nuts

Comment: Show a couple of complete error messages.

Comment: @rmaddy found the issue.  When adding the files to the project, even though the box was check marked, the files did not get added to the target.

Comment: You should delete this question.